# Altium castellated cut outs

Tags: altium

I have some trouble to design castellated cut outs for a pad, at least there is always thin copper area you can see in the pictures below. How can I get rid of this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like an artifact of your 3D rendering program, and wouldn't appear in real life. It appears not to understand that when a hole overlaps another hole or the board outline, there's no plating in that area.

Comment: Well, thats true, but i first had the edge directly at the edge of the castellated hole and the chinese manufacturer produces that exactly that way, though I told him to get rid of it.

Comment: Altium's support for castellated holes is awkward at best. You're best to generate the full holes and indicate on your fabrication drawing that these are to be castellated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having two holes (one round and one rectangular?) you can create one plated slot.  That would get rid of the internal plated wall pointed to by the red DOWN pointing arrow.  Design it such that the end that you don't want fully hangs over the edge of the board.  When the fab house routes the PCB, they will cut out any unwanted plating.  You just need to call out routing for depanelization on the edges that have this feature to ensure you get what you want.